# ASP.Net Mixed Content errors on IIS

Tags: asp.net, razor, mixed-content

When I deploy to our IIS server I get mixed content errors for my javascript.

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/myapp' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://example.com/myapp/js/lib/jquery.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

User .net 4.6.1 ASP.Net MVC. Here is my script block in index.cshtml.

```
<script src="~/js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You showed us the script declaration from your Razor file, right?  What does the actual HTML that gets rendered look like?

Comment: You should check your _layout.cshtml file in the shared folder for possible script tags that were added trough default nuget packages upon creating the project.

Comment: @mason <script src="/myapp/js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>